# My ubuntu does not go to blank screen

Tags: power-management, screensaver

In my power settings I have setup automatic Blank Screen in a minute however it does not go to blank.
This is a laptop Lenovo Thinkpad.
How to fix this?
Is there at least any way I can manually activate blank screen or a screen saver?
Also I want it to go to blank screen when I lock my laptop, it goes to blank for a moment but then it awakes.

[image]

Comment: If you use your mouse/keyboard during the period, it will reset the timer. source: my mother's lubuntu laptop and my kubuntu desktop

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but can you try enabling or disabling the sleep settings.

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target` and `sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target`

just like sleep settings we also have `suspend.target`, `hibernate.target` and also `hybrid-sleep.target`.

Playing with these might solve your problem.